# Do annealed energies underestimate quenched energies?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability, disorder

In the physics of disordered systems, there are two ways to treat the disorder:

- Quenched disorder, in which the disordered variables are considered to be frozen with respect to the thermodynamic processes one is interested in. The variables are drawn from a probability distribution $\mu$, and subsequently taken as constant.
- Annealed disorder, in which the disorder variables are themselves thermodynamic degrees of freedom.

Suppose the disordered variables are given by $J$, a vector drawn from the distribution $\mu$. Let us write the partition function of the quenched system, with disorder variables $J$, as $Z(\beta | J)$, where $\beta$ is the inverse temperature. Further, denote expectation with respect to $\mu$ by $\mathbb{E}(\cdot)$. The partition function of the annealed system is then $Z_a(\beta) = \mathbb{E}(Z(\beta | J))$.

Literature concerning disordered systems points out that the average energy of the quenched system is given exactly by:

$$
\langle E \rangle_Q = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \mathbb{E} (\ln Z(\beta | J)).
$$

In contrast, the annealed average energy is

$$
\langle E \rangle_A = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln Z_a(\beta)
= -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln \mathbb{E}(Z(\beta | J)).
$$

The latter quantity is usually easier to treat, but also incorrect.

I am curious about the relationship between these two energies. Specifically, I'm wondering if it holds that $\langle E \rangle_A \leq \langle E \rangle_Q$.

It seems intuitive to believe so, since the annealed system treats the disorder variables as degrees of freedom. I'd therefore expect that the Gibbs measure favors those values of $J$ that yield smaller energies on average. Moreover, numerical experiments where I simulate the thermodynamics of a combinatorial optimization problem (TSP) corroborate this. But I can't find any rigorous or even informal proofs of this fact, and finding one myself is proving harder than I'd thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a proof, but need some time to think about it. In the meantime, here is a sketch:

---

First, for $\alpha \in [0, 1]$, define the function
$$
U(\alpha) := -\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln \mathbb{E}(Z(\beta | J)^\alpha), \quad \alpha \in (0, 1],
$$
with $U(0)$ defined as the limit of this expression as $\alpha \to 0^+$. It can be shown that $U(1) = \langle E \rangle_A$, while $U(0) = \langle E \rangle_Q$. It then remains to show that $U$ is decreasing on $[0, 1]$. Directly doing this seems hard, but I've been able to show that $U'(0) \leq 0$. One can then show that $U$ is one-to-one on $[0, 1]$ for $\beta > 0$ (*). Together with continuity in $\alpha$, this implies monotonicity for $U$, and since $U'(0) \leq 0$, we have $U'(\alpha) \leq 0$ for all $\alpha \in [0, 1]$.

---

There are some details I still need to fill in; particularly, the step marked with (*). Once I'm confident the proof is correct, I will edit the rest in this answer.

---

Edit: it's all far simpler than I thought it was. Just assume the converse, integrate, and arrive at a contradiction to Jensen's inequality.